# Why does transmission-daemon need to access my user dirs when run as a system user?

Tags: sudo, transmission

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, and have a fresh install of `transmission-daemon`. It runs fine as a Systemd service. But when I try to run it standalone (with the service stopped), I see:

```
~ ⌘ sudo -u debian-transmission transmission-daemon -f --log-error --log-info --log-debug
[2019-05-14 11:53:19.167] Couldn't read "/home/jason/.config/user-dirs.dirs": Permission denied
[2019-05-14 11:53:20.419] Couldn't create "/home/jason/.config/transmission-daemon": Permission denied (file-posix.c:189)
[2019-05-14 11:53:20.419] Couldn't create "/home/jason/.config/transmission-daemon": Permission denied (file-posix.c:189)
[2019-05-14 11:53:20.419] Couldn't create "/home/jason/.config/transmission-daemon": Permission denied (file-posix.c:189)
[2019-05-14 11:53:20.419] Transmission 2.92 (14714) started (session.c:740)
[2019-05-14 11:53:20.419] Couldn't read "/home/jason/.config/transmission-daemon/stats.json": No such file or directory (utils.c:238)
[2019-05-14 11:53:20.419] Couldn't read "/home/jason/.config/transmission-daemon/stats.benc": No such file or directory (utils.c:238)
```

Note that `~` does resolve to `/home/jason` as the user `jason` (me). But I'm running it as the user `debian-transmission`. So why is Transmission trying to access "my" user directories? How can I stop it doing that?

Comment: If you want `sudo` to change `$HOME` to that of the target user, you need to add `-H` I think?

Comment: @steeldriver aaa(character limit satisfied here)aaaaaaaaaaargh

Comment: @steeldriver That was the problem, I wonder if the default policy changed recently? Anyway, post it as an answer, it really was that simple. (Not sure what happens when Systemd runs it, but not really important.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in recent versions of Ubuntu, `sudo` is configured to preserve the invoking user's `HOME` environment variable<sup>1</sup>. You can verify this either by executing something like

```
$ sudo -u testuser sh -c 'echo $HOME'
/home/steeldriver
```

or by running `sudo sudo -V` and looking at the `Environment variables to preserve` section.

In order to set `HOME` to that of the target user, you can add `-H` (`--set-home`) option:

> ```
>  -H, --set-home
>              Request that the security policy set the HOME environment
>              variable to the home directory specified by the target user's
>              password database entry.  Depending on the policy, this may
>              be the default behavior.
> ```

Ex.

```
$ sudo -Hu testuser sh -c 'echo $HOME'
/home/testuser
```

---

1. See also [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/a/270019/178692)